# Eliminate webex annoyances

Tags: webex

I have a number of clients that use webex for conference calls.  The process to actually join a meeting is cumbersome and I'd like to make it less so.

The process:

- clicking the 'webex' link in an email
- which launches a launches a browser
- which starts webex's client (Java?)
- which asks me to supply my name and email address
- which allows you to join the meeting
- finally, provide your telephone # so the meeting will call you

Is there a way to get webex just to call me when the meeting starts, rather than having to follow this tiresome process?

In lieu of this, how do I get webex to save my name, email address, and telephone # so I don't need to provide them each time?

Comment: Why even bother with telephone calls? Using a PC headset offers superior audio quality.

Comment: Two reasons: 1) I don't have a PC headset, 2) I may be in my car when the meeting occurs.